# redis get and set key expiry with transaction

Tags: scala, redis

I am using etaty redisscala (https://github.com/etaty/rediscala) client. Here is my function

```
private def getVersionTime(db: RedisClient, interval: Long)(implicit ec: ExecutionContext): Future[Long] = {

import akka.util.ByteString
import redis.ByteStringFormatter

implicit val byteStringLongFormatter = new ByteStringFormatter[Long] {
  def serialize(data: Long): ByteString = ByteString(data.toString.getBytes)
  def deserialize(bs: ByteString): Long = bs.utf8String.toLong
}

db.get[Long]("versionTime").map {
  case Some(v) => loggerF.info(s"Retrieved version time ${v}")
    v
  case None => val current = System.currentTimeMillis()
    db.setex[Long]("versionTime", (current / 1000) + interval, current)
    loggerF.info(s"set version time ${current}")
    current
}
```

}

Here is my test. This test calls above method

```
it("check with multiple tasks"){
  val target = 10
  val latch = new java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch(target)
  (1 to target).map{t =>
    getVersionTime(prodDb, 10).map{r => print("\n" + r); latch.countDown()}
  }
  assert(latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
}
```

Output of test

14:52:46.692 [pool-1-thread-12] INFO  EndToEndITTests - set version time 1548062566687
14:52:46.693 [pool-1-thread-6] INFO  EndToEndITTests - set version time 1548062566687
14:52:46.693 [pool-1-thread-20] INFO  EndToEndITTests - set version time 1548062566687
14:52:46.692 [pool-1-thread-2] INFO  EndToEndITTests - set version time 1548062566686
14:52:46.692 [pool-1-thread-10] INFO  EndToEndITTests - set version time 1548062566687
14:52:46.693 [pool-1-thread-8] INFO  EndToEndITTests - set version time 1548062566687
14:52:46.692 [pool-1-thread-4] INFO  EndToEndITTests - set version time 1548062566686
14:52:46.692 [pool-1-thread-11] INFO  EndToEndITTests - set version time 1548062566687
14:52:46.692 [pool-1-thread-9] INFO  EndToEndITTests - set version time 1548062566687
14:52:46.692 [pool-1-thread-7] INFO  EndToEndITTests - set version time 1548062566687

Expected behaviour is - set version time should come once and for rest of the threads Retrieved version time should be printed. I think I need to use transaction here so that get and setex wrapped inside watch and exec

```
  private def getVersionTimeTrans(db: RedisClient, interval: Long): Long = {
    import akka.util.ByteString
    import redis.ByteStringFormatter

    implicit val byteStringLongFormatter = new ByteStringFormatter[Long] {
      def serialize(data: Long): ByteString = ByteString(data.toString.getBytes)
      def deserialize(bs: ByteString): Long = bs.utf8String.toLong
    }

    val redisTransaction = db.transaction()
    redisTransaction.watch("versionTime")
    val result: Future[Long] = redisTransaction.get[Long]("versionTime").map {
      case Some(v) => loggerF.info(s"Retrieved version time ${v}")
        v
      case None => val current = System.currentTimeMillis()
        redisTransaction.setex[Long]("versionTime", (current / 1000) + interval, current)
        loggerF.info(s"set version time ${current}")
        current
    }
    redisTransaction.exec()
    val r = for {
      i <- result
    } yield {
      i
    }
    Await.result(r, 10 seconds)
  }
```

test

```
it("check with multiple threads "){
  val target = 10
  val latch = new java.util.concurrent.CountDownLatch(target)
  (1 to target).map{t =>
    Future(getVersionTimeTrans(prodDb, 10)).map{r => latch.countDown()}
  }
  assert(latch.await(10, TimeUnit.SECONDS))
}
```

For this test too, output is same. I couldn't figure it how to wrap it inside transaction properly. Please help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solved the problem using LUA script

Answer (score 0):

Looking into the rediscala implementation it seems that you can't use optimistic locking that I suggested in the original answer (see below) because in rediscala the `TransactionBuilder` will not send the `WATCH` command until the `EXEC` command which makes it pretty useless. There is an old closed [bug on GitHub](https://github.com/etaty/rediscala/issues/26) which refers to another [SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750626/transactions-and-watch-statement-in-redis) with exactly this scenario and the answer is

> In rediscala, you can't read inside a transaction, because you will be blocking the client for other requests.
>   I suggest you try to look if you can do your check in a LUA script. (transform the transaction in a lua script)

and a few months later

> It is closed because **not advisable to implement** 
>   You should use http://redis.io/commands#scripting

It seems this is in the same state since the 2014 and I don't think it will ever be changed.

---

**Original answer**

I don't have alive Redis to test it, but looking into the [Redis transaction docs](https://redis.io/topics/transactions) it looks Redis do not support SQL-style transactions as it seems you imagine. It supports atomic operations but you can't do "start transaction-get data-check-possibly modify-commit" cycle. All the "get data" commands will be queued before finally an `EXEC` command arrives. It means you can't do any checks between get and set inside the same transaction.

If you look at the "*Optimistic locking using check-and-set*" section of that doc, you can see that the correct way to implement your behavior is:

1. Create a transaction with `watch` for the key
2. Get the value ***outside*** of the transaction
3. Check the value and if update is required, issue an update inside the transaction. (Don't forget to `UNWATCH` in case if no updates are required)
4. Execute the transaction
5. Check if the transaction failed, if so repeat the whole cycle. If not - you are the winner who written the value.